# A clear and good way to add custom fields to billing information

Tags: checkout, database, shipping, payment, billing

I have tried to search for direct information about how to add custom fields to my billing information checkout. Whatever page I visit, it tells me to buy an extension or it describes steps to implement it manually but nothing helped me yet. Is there a clear way to add or edit custom fields in the billing information with descriptions? Please help me out with this.

Answer (score 0):

```
app/design/frontend/yourtheme/default/template/checkout/onepage/billing.phtml
```

simply add your field

```
 <input type="text" title="<?php echo $this->__('Custom Fields ') ?>" name="billing[custom_field]" id="billing:custom>" class="input-text" />
```

add your event in your observer

```
<frontend>
<events>
      <checkout_type_onepage_save_order_after>
                <observers>
                    <modulename>
                      <type>singleton</type>
                        <class>modulename/observer</class>
                        <method>saveafterorder</method>
                    </modulename>
                </observers>
      </checkout_type_onepage_save_order_after>
    </events>
    </frontend>
```

your observer

```
class Spacename_Modulename_Model_Observer {
    public function saveafterorder($observer)
        {
                $event = $observer->getEvent(); 
                $order = $event->getOrder();
                $order_id=$order->getEntityId();


                $billing=Mage::app()->getRequest()->getPost('billing');
             echo   $billing['custom_field'];
         }}
```

Comment: Hi, not working for me (Magento 1.9.2.4). Observer is called but billing post data are not supplied.